# Sharing (binary substrings vs. mathematical property)?

Tags: number-theory, binary

Do the natural numbers whose binary (representations) strings share the same particular binary substring also share any mathematical property? One obvious example: when a single one-bit substring in the first binary place of any natural number is "1" that number is "odd" and when it is "0" that number is even. But my question refers generally to repeated multi-bit substrings among different distances of bits. For example consider these following numbers:

\begin{equation*}
13 \rightarrow \begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|}\hline \color{red}1&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
77 \rightarrow \begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}\hline 1&0&0&\color{red}1&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1\\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
893 \rightarrow \begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}\hline \color{red}1&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1&1&1&\color{red}1&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1\\ \hline
\end{array} \\
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
108237 \rightarrow \begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}\hline \color{red}1&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1&0&0&\color{red}1&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1&1&0&0&\color{red}1&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}1 \\ \hline
\end{array} \\
\end{equation*}

Is there any mathematically meaningful connection among the numbers of "13", "77", "893", "108237"?

Answer (score 1):

It somewhat depends on what you mean by "mathematical meaningful connection among the numbers..."

However, I would say in general the answer to your question is no. Consider that for any given binary string, as $n \to \infty$, the proportion of integers containing that binary string approaches $1$.  So in some sense almost all integers contain the given binary string as a substring.

As you note, if you know about specific bits in specific positions, that gives you more interesting information.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that they all end in the string $1101$ means that they are congruent $\mod 16$, for example. Numbers that all end in the same $n$ bits will be congruent $\mod 2^{n}$.

Comment: Can congruence relation be applied to strings in which any given substring is not at the head or tail of the them? I mean for the strings that don't begin or end with a particular substring?

Comment: No, this is dependent on the numbers ending with a particular string. Also, I'll point out that it's not unique to binary. For a possibly more familiar example, in base 10, numbers that end in the same $n$ digits are congruent $mod 10^n$. The same is not true if the matching string doesn't occur at the end of the number. For a simple non-example, take the number 11 and 12. They both start with the string "1" but they aren't congruent mod anything other than 1, which is pretty uninteresting.

Comment: @RobArthan no worries!